# Swift reading RTF file doesn't apply Tags

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsattributedstring, rtf

I'm reading a rtf file but output result shows me simple string containing tags, It doesn't appear as `NSAttributedString` as it should
here is my code

```
if let rtfPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SampleHTML", withExtension: "rtf") {
     do {
          let attributedStringWithRtf: NSAttributedString = 
          try NSAttributedString(url: rtfPath, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
          NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch let error {
            print("Got an error \(error)")
        }
}
```

After reading the file its shows attribute string as :
< p >< em>Review the following information. Then select the best answer and click < strong>Submit< /strong>. After answering, click < strong>Next Question< /strong> to move forward.< /em>< /p> .
    I've inserted spaces in tag to clarify the issue, without spaces StackOverflow applies tag to text, what am I missing here ?

Comment: I don't understand. Your file is called `SampleHTML.rtf`. Is that HTML or RTF? Its content seems like HTML to me, so replace `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf` with `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` (or something like that, don't remember the exact key). That's how the tafs in a RTF file are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax Does yours really have it? Is it HTML embeded into RTF? Because having rtf as the extension fil doesn't mean it's really "rtf"...

Comment: @Larme Sorry for the naming confusion actually its rtf file with HTML tag that's why its named SampleHTML

Comment: If it's really HTML embeded into RTF, then, after you need to do afterwards: `let htmlData = attributedStringWithRtf.string.data(using:.utf8)` and `let finalAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)` But could you give us the real content of that file (using `let contents = String(url:rtfPath)` (you can use the StackOverflow "code" tag to show the real contents, this way you don't have to add extra spaces to the html tags).

Comment: @Larme thanks it worked, post it as a answer, I'll accept it, with try catch of course :)

Comment: @Larme one last thing, how can I apply paragraph styles to final string? I've made `NSAttributedStringKey` dictionary, but don't know how to apply it on existing `NSAttributedString`

Comment: I'll post an answer as soon as you give the content the rtf file. My solution should indeed work, but the mixing RTF and HTML seems weird, overkill (and made you convert twice before having the final NSAttributedString) I prefer orient towards a better improvement than giving a hot fix.

Comment: @Larme this is content of rtf file : < p >< em>Review the following information. Then select the best answer and click < strong>Submit< /strong>. After answering, click < strong>Next Question< /strong> to move forward.< /em>< /p> .
I've inserted spaces in tag to clarify the issue, without spaces StackOverflow applies tag to text, what am I missing here ?

Comment: Keep the code you posted on your question and just change .rtf to .html, and tell me if it works. I’ll givr my answer then.

Comment: @Larme yeah it works but it adds many extra lines in the content too many ( \ ) symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After RTF to `NSAttributedString` you got (you can use code tag of SO to avoid the HTML tags to be interpreted):

```
<p><em>Review the following information. Then select the best answer and click <strong>Submit</strong>. After answering, click <strong>Next Question</strong> to move forward.</em></p>
```

So now, you have a HTML AttributedString.
 
And like RTF, there is a way to get `NSAttributedString` from HTML String.
So let's get first the HTML String: `let htmlString = attributedStringWithRtf.string`.
For the rest, the method is almost the same as the one with used, with changes: `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` instead of `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf` (seems obvious), and there is an init with `data` instead of path, so you just have to use `let htmlData = htmlString.data(using:.utf8)`

So the code:

```
let rtfPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SampleHTML", withExtension: "rtf") 
let attributedStringWithRtf: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(url: rtfPath, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
let htmlString = attributedStringWithRtf.string
let htmlData = htmlString.data(using:.utf8)
let attributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
```

**Note:** I am not using `if let`, `try`/`catch` on purpose because you already use them correctly, and I'm more interested in the logic behind your issue and how to get away with it.

Now, after discussion in comment:
You save HTML Text (ie with HTML tags) into a RTF file.
Clearly, that's overkill, because as you can see in the solution I gave you do twice the conversion to get the final `NSAttributedString`.
So, what I'd do is either use entirely RTF File, and set the RTF tags equivalent for `<p>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, etc instead of the HTML ones.
Save you HTML String (with HTML tags) in a simple `.txt`.

For instance, I saved a RTF File using *TextEdit.app*, and the real content is:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf830
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 myText}
```

And I just wrote `myText`, RTF adding a lot of if own tags.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, my application gets data containing html tags from a rtf file, for the purpose of just displaying to the user, it doesn't change the content. That's why I only needed a way to read data from rtf file & get attributed string with tags effect applied.